# Trigger VBA after RefreshAll

Tags: vba, excel

I have a query in excel which is pulling a bunch of data from another Spreadsheet. Next to this query I am consolidating some of the data into one line to fill a drop down list. Unfortunately the formulas are not updating properly after the Refresh All button is pressed.

I've managed to find a solution for autofilling the consolidated formula from the query:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Autofill_ListSource()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PartsLibrary")

    With ActiveSheet

        Lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            Range("AM2:AO2").Select
                Selection.Autofill Destination:=Range("AM2:AO" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault

    End With

End Sub
```

What I have struggled to do is find a way to call this Sub after Refresh All is triggered. How do I go about doing this? Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: Is the Calculations set to Automatic ?

Comment: @Kyoujin sorry, I don't quite understand. Are you referring to the query having an automatic refresh?

Comment: If it isnt updating formulas when you refresh all then check inside the Formula tab in Excel and check that Calculations is set to Manual or Automatic.

Comment: @Kyoujin I just checked and Calculations is set to Automatic. I may have done a bad job of explaining what is happening to the formulas once the query is refreshed. The issue occurs when new lines are pulled across to the query. Say 50 new lines are added to the query of previously 100 inputs in random locations, the consolidated formula table will only work up until row 100. As long as the new, randomly inserted data was within the first 100, they will be correct, anything beyond the 100 will show as #REF. The Autofill function fixes this but I would like this to trigger after a refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set trigger on SheetTableUpdate Event. Just three lines in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetTableUpdate(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As TableObject)
    Autofill_ListSource
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow... so simple. How didn't I think of this. Thank you!